# Initializing thread_local class members in C++

Tags: c++, pthreads, thread-local-storage

I'm trying to include `thread_local` variables in a class, and initialize them inside threads.

Here is the code snippet:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    thread_local static int i;
};

typedef struct Args {
    A *a;
    int i;
} Args;

void* print(void* ptr) {
    Args *args = (Args*) ptr;
    thread_local int A::i = args->i;
    // args->a->i = args->i;
    cout << "(In thread) A.i = " << args->a->i << endl;
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    A *a = new A();
    Args a1, a2;

    a1.a = a;
    a1.i = 10;
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &print, &a1);

    a2.a = a;
    a2.i = 20;
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &print, &a2);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    cout << "(In main) A.i = " << a->i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error I encounter is:

```
multithreaded_example.cpp: In function ‘void* print(void*)’:
multithreaded_example.cpp:21:24: error: qualified-id in declaration before ‘=’ token
  thread_local int A::i = args->i;
                        ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The static variable needs to be initialized with the `thread_local` prefix. Corrected code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    thread_local static int i;
};

thread_local int A::i = 0;

typedef struct Args {
    A *a;
    int i;
} Args;

void* print(void* ptr) {
    Args *args = (Args*) ptr;
    A::i = args->i;
    // args->a->i = args->i;
    cout << "(In thread) A.i = " << args->a->i << endl;
    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread1, thread2;
    A *a = new A();
    Args a1, a2;

    a1.a = a;
    a1.i = 10;
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &print, &a1);

    a2.a = a;
    a2.i = 20;
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &print, &a2);

    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    cout << "(In main) A.i = " << a->i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
(In thread) A.i = 10
(In thread) A.i = 20
(In main) A.i = 0
```